# Passing PHP variables into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have a function in PHP which inserts values into MYSQL tables.

```
function insertRow($db, $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant)
{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO " .$new_table. " VALUES(number, "string", "string")"
    $q = mysqli_query($db, $insert);
}
```

I am struggling customizing the VALUES part. I need the number, string, and string to be ID, Partner, and Merchant variables from PHP respectively.

I've tried

```
function insertRow($db, $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant)
{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO " .$new_table. " VALUES(" .$ID . $Partner . $Merchant . ")";
    $q = mysqli_query($db, $insert);
}
```

as well. But it doesn't seem to work because for SQL the string values must be surrounded with quotes. But if I change the code so that its ."$ID" . "$Partner" . "$Merchant" . ")"; and thus the variables are in quotes as needed, they are no longer PHP variables. How do I get my PHP variables to be included in quotes so that I can execute the SQL correctly?

Comment: Read up on database escaping.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers, using concatenation, are the simple ones. The best one is to use prepared statements, which will make your code significantly more secure.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO " .$new_table. " VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
$q = mysqli_prepare($db, $insert);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, "iss", $ID, $Partner, $Merchant);
mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
```

Doing parameterised queries means your query and the data are sent separately. This means that the structure of the query already exists, and so cannot be altered by anything else inserted in the data, which means you are safe from SQL injection.

See the PHP manual:

- [`mysqli_prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt_execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: This is the correct way to do this.  Without the parameters you are opening yourself up to attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many methods to possibilities to do this:

### String concatenation

be aware of the data type that the database except. In your question, you missed out the comma to seperate the values:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO ' . $new_table . ' VALUES(' . $ID . ', \'' . $Partner . '\', \'' . $Merchant '\')';
```

There are many ways to modify the string concatenation example. Consider the php documentation about single and double quotes. In you example you used double quotes in the meaning of single quotes. With double quotes you can put variables directly into it. So I changed it to single quotes.

### sprintf

```
$insert = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s VALUES(%s, \'%s\', \'%s\');', $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant);
```

see the documentation for more info about this handy function: http://www.php.net/sprintf

### Prepared Statements

I would rather advice you to use this method because of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). In the example above you need to take care about string escaping. May work with `mysql_real_escape`. But it may not work in all scenarios.

So, prepared statements are a lot better:

```
$insert = 'INSERT INTO ' .$new_table. ' VALUES(?, ?, ?)';
$q = mysqli_prepare($db, $insert);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, "iss", $ID, $Partner, $Merchant);
mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
```

PS: Using the object oriented way would be also better for prepared statement, because you got more opportunities to do this. See the documentation for `MySQLi` class style and for `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO " .$new_table. " VALUES(".$ID.", '".$Partner."', "."'"$Merchant"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function insertRow($db, $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant)
{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO " .$new_table. " VALUES( '" .$ID."','" . $Partner."','". $Merchant . "')";
    $q = mysqli_query($db, $insert);
}
```

Or you can use

```
function insertRow($db, $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant)
{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO " .$new_table. " VALUES( '$ID','$Partner','$Merchant')";
    $q = mysqli_query($db, $insert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um... it being a query makes no difference to the fact that it's just a string like any other. You were perfectly capable of adding in the `$new_table` value, so what's stopping you from doing the others?

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO ".$new_table." VALUES (".$ID.", '".$Partner."', '".$Merchant.")";
```

This assumes you already took the necessary steps to sanitise the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO $new_table VALUES(number, '{$string}', '{$string}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO $new_table VALUES($ID,'$Partner','$Merchant')";
```