# PHP variables necessary for insertion into SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have been trying for several days to get the proper formatting for what I wish to execute.

The goal is to insert rows into a MYSQL table which is previously created. The table may be a mix of strings and integers, and as we know MYSQL requires quotes around strings for insertion  while it does not for integers. So then, the proper way to insert something into a table of an integer and two strings would be:

```
insert into table values(number, "string", "string");
```

I wish the values to be php variables. However when I input the variables, the code will no longer produce the result when I check in MYSQL. The table will be created, but it will be empty. So it must be this statement that does not work.

This is my actual code for the function to insert it:

```
function insertRow($db, $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant)

    $insert = "INSERT INTO ".$new_table. " VALUES (1,'Partner','Merchant')";

    $q = mysqli_query($db, $insert);
```

It works like this, but fills the entire table with 1, partner and merchant for every row as many times as I choose.

I've also tried several variations like this

```
function insertRow($db, $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant)

    $insert = "INSERT INTO ".$new_table. " VALUES(" .$ID. "," ."'$Partner'". ","."'$Merchant'".")";

    $q = mysqli_query($db, $insert);
```

I've also tried these:

[Passing PHP variables into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163074/passing-php-variables-into-mysql)

but none have worked to actually insert the tables into the rows.

Does anyone have an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)?

Comment: Have you gotten the error message from the database? It'll be telling you what the problem is.

Comment: you can try echo $insert and then execute it directly in phpmyadmin. be sure to check the value returned by mysqli_query and if it's false,  print $mysqli->error to have more information on what went wrong

Comment: Not shown here, but I imagine you are reinforcing your code to prevent against SQL inj?

Comment: Agree with PeeHaa, if you will be inserted lots of data into the table, creating a string is not the best way as the db will have to parse the statement everytime it's repeated. A prepared statement will just parse it once and the use the same statement for subsequent inserts even with different data.  Also, prepared statements will help against SQL injection as mentioned by njk if you intend to have data passed to this function from a form of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your debugging very simply, and work from there. The first guess I would have is that you're not setting your parameter values properly that are passed into the function.

Try this:

```
function insertRow($db, $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant) {
  $ID=1;
  $Partner = 'Partner';
  $Merchant = 'Merchant';
  $insert = "INSERT INTO $new_table " .
    " VALUES($ID,'$Partner','$Merchant')";
  $q = mysqli_query($db, $insert);
  if (!$q) die(mysqli_error($db));
}
```

Does that work? If so, then the problem is that your parameter values are not being properly set.

Note that I've also added some error reporting in there ;-)

Note, though, that it's not a good idea to create your SQL like this. It is wide open to SQL injection. Much better to look into using Prepared Statements:

```
  $prep = mysqli_prepare($db, "insert into " . $new_table . " values (?,?,?)");
  $prep->bind_param("iss", $ID, $Partner, $Merchant);
  $prep->execute();
```

See the [PHP documentation on mysqli_prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for more details.

Comment: I tried using your second bit, it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Well, let's start with the first bit (setting the parameter values) - does that work?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks! I am interested in the other bit though too, making it a bit more secure seems nice.

Comment: Great - ok, I'm guessing then that the problem was that your parameters weren't set correctly?

Comment: No,  I really think it was just an issue of syntax. I think your escape characters with the proper method when mixing with sql

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT query looks pretty close.  I believe that your issue may arise from not terminating the SQL statement:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO " . $new_table . 
   " VALUES(" . $ID . ", '$Partner', '$Merchant');";
```

Note the extra semicolon (;), closing the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a feature that allows you to put variables into double-quoted strings.  Try running the query:

```
function insertRow($db, $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant)
    $insert = "INSERT INTO $new_table VALUES ($ID,'$Partner','$Merchant');";
    $q = mysqli_query($db, $insert);
```

The reason that this works is that PHP parses double-quoted strings to do a variable replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PDO prepared statements. It makes parameters easy:

```
function insertRow($db, $new_table, $ID, $Partner, $Merchant) {
   $host = 'host';
   $user = 'user';
   $password = 'password';
   $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $password);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO $new_table VALUES (:id, :partner, :merchant)";
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(':id', $ID);
   $stmt->bindValue(':partner', $Partner);
   $stmt->bindValue(':merchant', $Merchant);
   $result = $stmt->execute() || die(var_dump($stmt->errorInfo()));
 }
```

Here, $ID, $Partner, and $Merchant are automatically escaped, but you may need to escape $new_table in order to avoid SQL injection.